# how to upload data using POST request using params and body using ng2-file-upload angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file-upload

here i want to upload some data using "POST method with parameters & body". i am aware of post request but till now for upload i am using the "PUT Method" and sending request body below is my code

```
  this.upload= new FileUploader({ url: this.service.dataUpload('/uploadFile'), queueLimit: 999, method: 'PUT' });
    this.upload.onBeforeUploadItem = (item) => {
      debugger;
      item.withCredentials = false;
    };
    //Call back for uploaded
    this.upload.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {


         console.log("This is file name::",data['file']['name']);

//It Contains Object
         console.log("data::",this.DataTemplate[data['file']['name']]);

      if(status == 0){

        this.service.saveData(this.DataTemplate[data['file']['name']])
          .subscribe(res => { console.log(res.status); });
        return;
      }


      var responsePath = JSON.parse(response);

      if (status == 201) {


        this.DataTemplate[data['file']['name']]['url'] = response.download;

      }

    };

    this.upload.onBuildItemForm = (item, form) => {

      let name = data['file']['name'];
      form.append("data", data['file']['rawFile']);
      form.append("desc", JSON.stringify(this.fileMap[name]));


    };
  }


  uploadData(){
  // For uploading Data
   this.upload.uploadAll();
}
```

this.DataTemplate[data['file']['name']] **it contains the below object**

```
{
  "product": "laptop",
  "info": {
    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
    "file_id": "dfldpf9c",
    "author": "unknown"
  },
  "Sr_id": "dfldpf9c"
```

}

here my issue is **How can i send the "Sr_id" as parameter to the post request **
like below

```
 this.upload= new FileUploader({ url: this.service.dataUpload('/uploadFile/{**Sr_id**}'), queueLimit: 999, method: 'POST' });
        this.upload.onBeforeUploadItem = (item) => {
          debugger;
          item.withCredentials = false;
        };
```

Comment: Have not tried the plugin. You can use query string parameter `"/path/to/server?id=" + Sr_id` at the URL then parse the request URL at the server.

Comment: @guest271314 yeah but I'd is created is a array I mean more than 1record so for  1record 1id for n number of records n number of IDs so how can send these and .onComplete method  I'm getting the id

Comment: Can you include what `Sr_id` is in code at the question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It in my sample json object I updated in the question

Comment: Are you trying to `POST` `{
  "product": "laptop",
  "info": {
    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
    "file_id": "dfldpf9c",
    "author": "unknown"
  },
  "Sr_id": "dfldpf9c"
}` to the server?

Comment: Yes that is body and in that Sr_id will be parameter

Comment: Can `{ "product": "laptop", "mimetype": "image/jpeg", "file_id": "dfldpf9c", "author": "unknown", "Sr_id": "dfldpf9c" }` be substituted for `{ "product": "laptop", "info": { "mimetype": "image/jpeg", "file_id": "dfldpf9c", "author": "unknown" }, "Sr_id": "dfldpf9c" }`?

Comment: No as the format is already fixed so we need to send data like this and may I know is there any issue with this?

Comment: You can use `fetch()` and `FormData()` to `POST` the `File` object and additional data to the server.